# A command for discord bot to say server amd channel name

Tags: python, pycharm, discord, bots, mention

I need help with `{server}` and with the `{channel}`. I can't make the bot say the server name and the channel name.

```
@client.command()
async def whereami(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'You are on {server} on {channel}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server and channel is not defined. The ctx argument is an object which has two attributes which you are looking for; the guild and channel (guild is what they are called in Discord, not servers). So by using ctx.channel and ctx.guild you can access the guild and channel objects.

```
@client.command()
async def whereami(ctx):
   await ctx.send(f'You are on {ctx.guild} on {ctx.channel}')
```

You can read more about all the attributes in the offical docs:
[discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)